# Aser titasher Talmud bavli Taanith 9a-b

Tags: grammar-dikduk, mitzvah, maaser-tithes, aramaic, masechet-taanis

As for the advice to give maaser kesafim, מעשׁר כספים to become rich:
[Talmud Bavli Taánith 9a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.9a.1?lang=bi)
עַשֵּׂ֣ר תְּעַשֵּׂ֔ר becomes תִּתְעַשֵּׁר עַשֵּׂ֣ר.
Why does the Talmud uses ithpael ThiTh’ASheeR in stead of just Qal Taa’ASheR:?
Using qal only changes שׂ into שׁ. That would be more impressive, because in that case you have exactly the same letters!
Is there anybody who investigated this?

Comment: I don’t believe the verb לעשר in piel or לעשור in qal exists. There is להעשיר - to enrich others and להתעשר - to get rich. What would לעשר mean?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I understand better why Talmud have to use ithpael ִּתתעשׁר. Indeed I did not found לעשר in Jastrov.  I supposed that the qal of עָשַׁר, that could mean to be rich. That would better fit to the smooth transition from the mitzwah maaser to the reward of becoming rich.

Comment: The Talmud's statement was referring to מעשר, and it is not obvious that this extends to מעשר כספים (whose level of obligation is debated by the *poskim*). However, the Tur (YD 247) does extend the Rabbi Yochanan's statements here about *ma'aseir* to general charity and, implicitly, to *ma'aseir k'safim* (הדבר בדוק ומנוסה כי בשביל הצדקה שנותן לא יחסר לו אלא אדרבה תוסיף לו עושר וכבוד... וכתיב (מלאכי ג) הביאו את כל המעשר אל בית האוצר ויהי טרף בביתי ובחנוני נא בזאת... והריקותי עליכם ברכה עד בלי די ואמרו חכמים בכל דבר אסור לנסות את ה' חוץ מדבר זה כדכתיב "ובחנוני נא בזאת).